# How to share only on twitter?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm aware I can use the [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class to share something on my favourite social network. I'm trying to add a button to share on twitter only. I don't want to enable the user to chose.

I can't find a workaround for that class, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to share something with social networks. Few are:

- [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
  User will not have to SIgnIn, but would be presented with many networks.
- External Browser Mechanism (Recommended)
  You can launch a popup with BrowserControl in it and redirect it to URL of form
  `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=your-tweet-text&url=http://google.com`.
  User will be asked to SIgnIN with all text filled and ready to Tweet, as shown (Desktop Browser)
  [image]
- Dedicated WP Libraries such as [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp), [LINQtoTwitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) n [others](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).
  These will require you to use API 1.1 and send OAuth authenticated requests. Its a little comples if you only want Share capability.

Comment: I didn't know about the second option, that looks like a good option for me! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah...n its officially supported by Twitter too. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possil using the `ShareLinkTask`. You need to implement it by yourself, e.g: using [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp).